# How to resync development projects to github after git uninstalled / re-installed from OS X?

Tags: macos, git, github

I believe git, somehow, was uninstalled during an update of OS X.  I have reinstalled git and I want to re-sync my local development folders to the appropriate github repos but am not sure how.

I have since created a new repo so my github account is linked properly, but I don't know how to link the existing stuff.

For example, say one project is located at:

/users/stephen/development/cs

and it's corresponding github SSH location is at:

git@github.com:stephen/cs.git

How do I get these synced back up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that "git was somehow uninstalled", I assume you mean you cannot use the command `git` and you get `-bash: git: command not found` error. So the following should help.

#### Is `git` installed?

The first thing to do is type `which git` and that will tell you if its included in your path. If nothing is prints, then you know thats your first problem:

1. It's not installed, or
2. It is installed, but not included in your `$PATH`.

The solution to these problems, obviously, is [install it](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git)  or find it on your system. Typically on Mac OSX, it is found in  `/usr/bin/git`. Add it to your `$PATH` like so:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH
```

in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` (substitute `/user/bin` with the directory where you find `git`. )

#### Does the `git` repository still exists?

Now, check that the is repo didn't get destroyed. Most likely, it did not.

```
$ cd project/
$ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  staff  102 May 24 18:31 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 user  staff  204 May 24 18:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 user  staff  306 May 24 18:31 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  119 May 24 18:34 README.md
```

The presence of the `.git` directory means it still exists, therefore finding/installing `git` is your only problem. As soon as you fix that problem, you should be able to use `git` exactly how you used to.

However, if the `.git` file is gone (highly unlikely), there are several things you can do.

1. If you know your directory was in a clean state (all committed changes) and pushed to github before your loss, you can just delete the directory on your local machine and pull in a new fresh copy of the repo (easiest).
2. If you know your repo was clean, but NOT pushed to github OR you had a dirty directory (with changes not committed), you are in a bad spot. However, it is not impossible to regain your repo to its original state. Without knowing your repo directory structure, I can't go into too much detail. But the following should work for most cases:

   1. Initialize a new repo in the project directory.
   2. Add all files and commit.
   3. Add the remote repository
   4. Pull down the repo to merge them together.
   5. Resolve conflicts.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I think even if git was uninstalled, the repo didn't lose its identity. Did you try `git status` command on that repo? What does it say? Moreover I would try `git init` & adding remote after taking a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Git repositories are just collections of files, independent of the Git tool itself. Uninstalling Git does not delete the repositories, so your old origin is probably still there.

```
cd /users/stephen/development/cs
git remote -v
```

If you see your old origin, point it to the new location:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:stephen/cs.git
git fetch origin
```

If you don't see your old origin, add it...

```
git remote add -f origin git@github.com:stephen/cs.git
```

...and set up the trackers for existing local branches:

```
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
git branch --set-upstream another-local-branch origin/a-remote-branch-to-be-tracked
etc.
```